# How can I send attachments in an email reply?

Tags: python, email, attachment, email-attachments, exchangelib

I'm using the exchangelib package to connect to Exchange. I need to send attachments in a reply. When I send a normal message I add the attachment to the Message object like this:

```
message = Message()
message.account = account
message.subject = 'subject'
message.body = 'text'
message.to_recipients = [Mailbox(email_address='example@gmail.com')]
message.cc_recipients = ['example2@gmail.com']

for attachment in attachments or []:
    with open(attachment['path'], 'rb') as f:
        file = FileAttachment(name=attachment['file_name'], content=f.read())
        message.attach(file)
```

and to send a reply:

```
reply = message.reply(
    subject='Re: subject',
    body='texto',
    to_recipients=['example@gmail.com']
)
```

This works, but I don't now how to add attachments to the reply. I tried to set the attributes "attachments" and "attach" but the object doesn't have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Message.reply()` method creates and sends a `ReplyToItem` item which doesn't support attachments. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/replytoitem

So if you want to send a reply that has attachments, just create a normal Message item that has a `'Re: some subject'` title, contains the attachment, and quotes the original message, if that's needed.

Comment: Hi @Erik Cederstrand , can you please guide me with a sample code on how to "quote" the original message? I also have a requirement to send attachment with reply

Comment: You can use any quoting style you like in email replies. There's some examples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posting_style. You'll have to build the text message yourself. Attaching files to a Message is described in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#attachments